# table or view does not exist when using insert into

Tags: oracle-10g

I'm trying to insert into but getting the "table or view does not exist" error.

It tells me the specific line where the error occurs but I can't figure out what the problem is:

```
INSERT INTO c_ord_cur (ordid, total)
          VALUES (v_ord_rec.ordid, v_ord_rec.total);
```

I have already created the Table and it shows it on the left panel of oracle:
[image]

I'm using oracle developer sql, any ideas what is causing this problem?

Whole code:

```
Set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    CURSOR c_ord_cur IS 
    SELECT 
 *
    FROM            
      shoba.ord;

    v_ord_rec   c_ord_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN c_ord_cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_ord_cur into v_ord_rec;
        EXIT WHEN c_ord_cur%NOTFOUND;


        IF v_ord_rec.orderdate between '01/01/2009' and '31/12/2009' THEN
                INSERT INTO c_ord_cur (ordid, total)
              VALUES (v_ord_rec.ordid, v_ord_rec.total);
            dbms_output.put_line(v_ord_rec.orderdate||' is in ords86');
    END IF;

    IF v_ord_rec.orderdate between '01/01/2010' and '31/12/2010' THEN
                INSERT INTO c_ord_cur (ordid, total)
          VALUES (v_ord_rec.ordid, v_ord_rec.total);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_ord_rec.orderdate||' is in ords87');
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_ord_cur;

    COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: I do not see the table `C_ORD_CUR`.

Comment: Sorry, c_ord_cur is a cursor, i will upload more code.

Comment: I suppose that the database user `shoba` is the owner of the table `ord`? Who is executing the code? Does it have `select` rights on this table?

Comment: I'm the owner of ord. I created ord by copying shoba.ord columns using create table as, now I'm trying to take the record from shoba.ord and organize it, for example 2009 records in 2009 table, and 2010 in 2010 table etc..

Comment: So you can do an `select count(*) from shoba.ord;`? Also add the complete code that you execute when you get the *table or view does not exist*. With this it is not easy to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I can do that without any errors, I have access to that table. I will put the whole code up now, should have done it from the beginning, sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27134/discussion-between-almost-a-beginner-and-marco).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the definition `v_ord_rec   c_ord_cur%ROWTYPE;` that is wrong. It must be `v_ord_rec   shoba.ord%ROWTYPE;`. Also the insert statements should insert into real table and not into the cursor.